# Is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{n^n}{n(n-1)^{n-1}}\right] = e$ true?

Tags: number-theory

I know of  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}-\frac{n^n}{(n-1)^{n-1}}\right] = e$$

But it seems that

$$\frac{n^n}{n(n-1)^{n-1}}$$

also approximates $e$ for $n\to \infty$.

It can also be formulated as

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{10^{n\log n - (n-1)\log(n-1)}}{n}\right] = e$$
which looks less elegant, but makes it easier to check large $n$'s on your calculator

Comment: Yes by argument by Wolfram:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5Bn%5En+%2F+(n(n-1)%5E(n-1))%2Cn-%3Einf%5D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes because
$$\frac{n^n}{n(n-1)^{n-1}}=\frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)^{n-1}}=\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}$$